# How can I uniquely identify my php pages and then use that identifier in my php queries?

Tags: php, mysql

At the top of every php page on my website is a large profile card that calls data from a relational database in mySQL. This is the only thing I'm using the database for.

When I create new pages, I have to go through the code and update the id# for all of the php queries in the profile card. It's not hard. I just do a 'find and replace all' and I'm done.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to just put the id# at the top of the page once and have all of the php queries reference that id number. If this is possible, I'll be able to move that bulky profile code to my header.php page which already contains the template and menu stuff.

The only software I use is notepad++ and xampp.

Comment: can you show the code which you want to put in the header.php?

Comment: What? Most sites have one php page that takes a param in the GET query that identifies the page's content. example.com/?page=about - then in the query `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title = 'about';`

Comment: Mike B, I'm not using PHP in that way. :) All of my pages are static. I use php to parse the page so my content is separate from my template and menu (php includes) and to call data from the database.

Comment: @AmandaDay I would suggest using PHP's [magic `__FILE__` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and creating a map located in a config file shared by all your pages. The map would provide whatever ID is necessary for your queries to function. ex: `array('about.php' => 1, 'profile.php' => 2)`

Comment: THANKS! That sounds like just what I need. :) :) :) Sorry for my newbieness. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a constant in a `config.php`:

```
define('MY_ID', 12);
```

In each of your file:

```
include('config.php');
```

So you need to change the value of it only once.

A much better way, if you write a function, what gives you back this whole profile section, so you can change the layout of this also, in 1 place.

Comment: I think she's saying she copy/pastes an existing php file to create a new 'page'.. then she finds/replaces the ID in the copied file to correspond to the row in the db. Could be wrong.

Comment: It does not matter. If she do what i say, she needs to just delete the id, and replace it with `include('config.php');`

Comment: You're not understanding me. She copies about.php to create profile.php. Opens profile.php and changes the queries to filter on profile instead of about. A unified config does nothing for that situation.

Comment: Mike B is right. I need to call a specific ID from the database for each new page. The database is massive. I made it out of a multipage excel file. That was a trip. I don't need a page for each database entry. I just need to be able to call a specific line from it when I add new pages to the website. :)